# How to access AWS .env variables inside the ECS container in an angular app?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services

I am using ECR to store an Angular app that goes in as an image. Now I have keys, URLs, etc that I wish to access inside the container running on ECS, passed through in the ECS container definitions.

I have tried `dotenv` that dynamically picks up env variables and write the file `environment.ts` everytime you do an `npm start` but the issue with this is, that when an image is being built it is again hardcoded in the file and not something that is being accessed through a containers environment, where the ECS environment variables are.

I have no idea how to do that since `process.env` does not work in an angular environment, and I believe it won't work either since the Angular app is essentially just HTML, CSS, and JS after being built (No node server whatsoever).

So, In such a scenario, How do I even make environment variables work?

Comment: I've been trying to figure out this same issue for the pass week now =/

Comment: Apparently, there is no solution for this, it will be hardcoded at the end. It's like you have to use AWS store for it.